# Allow incoming connections from Google Translate only

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a small web server running on port 80, and I'd like to allow only Google Translate to have access to it.

First I tried running `dig translate.google.com` and `dig translate.googleusercontent.com` to get the IP address for it, which returned addresses ranging from **74.125.234.74** to **74.125.234.110**.

Then I opened the mentioned ports, but it did not work. Looking at iptables logs, I found Google has very different IP addresses to open the target website for translation. In a few tests they ranged from **74.125.186.40** to **74.125.187.169**.

Now, what I've got so far is the following rule, that opens the door for this range:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m iprange --src-range 74.125.186.40-74.125.187.169 -j ACCEPT
```

The problems:

1. Everytime Google tries to access the page, it uses a different IP address, and probably **out of the range** I mentioned previously. I'd have to try many many times to take note of all the range.
2. I'm concerned about the security implications also, since I don't know whether all IPs in the range are safe to leave open (would they all belong to Google?)

I tried `nslookup 74.125.186.40` to see if I could get a domain name for it, but it returns:

```
** server can't find 40.186.125.74.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? This sounds like a bad solution to a larger problem.

Comment: I need Google Translate to serve me personal files translated in a browser window.

Comment: And *why* are you seeking to block all other traffic? What are you trying to gain?

Comment: I don't think I need to allow access to the whole world if only Google Translate is to have access to my machine. Also, it is just a simple `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` server, since I need it only for that purpose.

Comment: So do that appropriately, blocking everyone else is a poor method of doing this. I assume all data is being returned upon request? If so, just block everything incoming that isn't in an established or related state. *That* would be the appropriate way to handle it.

Comment: I have the rule `-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` but don't understand how it really works actually :)

Comment: Essentially, since you already made the connection to the server, the connection is already established before it reaches the `INPUT` chain (it already came through your `OUTPUT` chain). Simply using that rule in conjunction with a default drop policy on your `INPUT` chain will do what you want without having to trawl through IP ranges.

Comment: You should use https://developers.google.com/translate/ instead.

Comment: @ChrisDown it doesn't work this way. The incoming connection is not related, since I do the request on the web browser, and then Google comes from another IP and visits my web server as it would do upon translating any other website.

Comment: It's not actually that expensive, and it sounds like your plan is basically to misuse and take advantage of their web service.

Comment: @mattdm I'm not misusing it. It allows me to translate a web page, and it requires javascript. So, parsing the returned data would be impossible for me. I use it according to what they offer me for my personal use. I'm not breaking the TOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this effectively. You aren't going to be able to count on any particular block of IPs for any known length of time.

Now, there are a couple of ways of solving your problem.

1. cut&paste what you need to translate into Google Translate. You can use `cat file | xclip -i` to do this for even a fairly long file if you have the *xclip* package installed.
2. If you are using a fairly solid web server, make a directory for it to serve that has a very long and random name. Use `mkdir $(dd if=/dev/random bs=21 count=1 | base64)` to create the directory so it has a truly random name. Make sure you have to include that directory name in the URL. This will set it up so someone has to know a secret in order to get at any of the files. Of course, you have to make sure the parent directory cannot be listed through the web server, otherwise it's trivial to figure out what the 'secret' directory name is.

Comment: Hi, @Omnifarious. I actually can't tell how safe `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80` is, but it does allow directory listing on `http://myipaddress`. Maybe there's some additional CLI parameter that I am unware of. Also, I was thinking, if I open the port for something like 74.125.186.0/8-74.125.187.0/8, will this range belong to Google only? If so, I think it would be safe, wouldn't it?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior: Do `chmod a-r` on the directory after you create the 'secret' directory in it. That should stop your webserver from listing that directory. Relying on the IP address mapping is just going to eventually get you in trouble, and IMHO is actually less secure than the secret directory idea.

Comment: @TeresaeJunior: You know, I would do both. The layers of protection complement each other well. Though they are both weak against an attacker in the middle.

Comment: I had a look at the documentation for SimpleHTTPServer, and I can avoid directory listing by providing an index.htm file, and it also doesn't allow parent directory listing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And make sure to add a `robots.txt` to tell search engines not to index the site.